# Forecasting using ARDL model in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, ardl

I am working on this data where I have used the  ARDL model. I want to plot the future intervals and though the model output is good I want to see the forecasting plots. Plus, I  have used the ardlDlm function to obtain the model output. Can someone please help me? Below is the data attached.

Data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1617235200, 1617321600, 1617408000, 
1617494400, 1617580800, 1617667200, 1617753600, 1617840000, 1617926400, 
1618012800, 1618099200, 1618185600, 1618272000, 1618358400, 1618444800, 
1618531200, 1618617600, 1618704000, 1618790400, 1618876800, 1618963200, 
1619049600, 1619136000, 1619222400, 1619308800, 1619395200, 1619481600, 
1619568000, 1619654400, 1619740800, 1619827200, 1619913600, 1.62e+09, 
1620086400, 1620172800, 1620259200, 1620345600, 1620432000, 1620518400, 
1620604800, 1620691200, 1620777600, 1620864000, 1620950400, 1621036800, 
1621123200, 1621209600, 1621296000, 1621382400, 1621468800, 1621555200, 
1621641600, 1621728000, 1621814400, 1621900800, 1621987200, 1622073600, 
1622160000, 1622246400, 1622332800, 1622419200, 1622505600, 1622592000, 
1622678400, 1622764800, 1622851200, 1622937600, 1623024000, 1623110400, 
1623196800, 1623283200, 1623369600, 1623456000, 1623542400, 1623628800, 
1623715200, 1623801600, 1623888000, 1623974400, 1624060800, 1624147200, 
1624233600, 1624320000, 1624406400, 1624492800, 1624579200, 1624665600, 
1624752000, 1624838400, 1624924800, 1625011200, 1625097600, 1625184000, 
1625270400, 1625356800, 1625443200, 1625529600, 1625616000, 1625702400, 
1625788800, 1625875200, 1625961600, 1626048000, 1626134400, 1626220800, 
1626307200, 1626393600, 1626480000, 1626566400, 1626652800, 1626739200, 
1626825600, 1626912000, 1626998400, 1627084800, 1627171200, 1627257600, 
1627344000, 1627430400, 1627516800, 1627603200, 1627689600, 1627776000, 
1627862400, 1627948800, 1628035200, 1628121600, 1628208000, 1628294400, 
1628380800, 1628467200, 1628553600, 1628640000, 1628726400, 1628812800, 
1628899200, 1628985600, 1629072000, 1629158400, 1629244800, 1629331200, 
1629417600, 1629504000, 1629590400, 1629676800, 1629763200, 1629849600, 
1629936000, 1630022400, 1630108800, 1630195200, 1630281600, 1630368000, 
1630454400, 1630540800, 1630627200, 1630713600, 1630800000, 1630886400, 
1630972800, 1631059200, 1631145600, 1631232000, 1631318400, 1631404800, 
1631491200, 1631577600, 1631664000, 1631750400, 1631836800, 1631923200, 
1632009600, 1632096000, 1632182400, 1632268800, 1632355200, 1632441600, 
1632528000, 1632614400, 1632700800, 1632787200, 1632873600, 1632960000, 
1633046400, 1633132800, 1633219200, 1633305600, 1633392000, 1633478400, 
1633564800, 1633651200, 1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 1633996800, 
1634083200, 1634169600, 1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 1634515200, 
1634601600, 1634688000, 1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 1635033600, 
1635120000, 1635206400, 1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 1635552000, 
1635638400, 1635724800, 1635811200, 1635897600, 1635984000, 1636070400, 
1636156800, 1636243200, 1636329600, 1636416000, 1636502400, 1636588800, 
1636675200, 1636761600, 1636848000, 1636934400, 1637020800, 1637107200, 
1637193600, 1637280000, 1637366400, 1637452800, 1637539200, 1637625600, 
1637712000, 1637798400, 1637884800, 1637971200, 1638057600, 1638144000, 
1638230400, 1638316800, 1638403200, 1638489600, 1638576000, 1638662400, 
1638748800, 1638835200, 1638921600, 1639008000, 1639094400, 1639180800, 
1639267200, 1639353600, 1639440000, 1639526400, 1639612800, 1639699200, 
1639785600, 1639872000, 1639958400, 1640044800, 1640131200, 1640217600, 
1640304000, 1640390400, 1640476800, 1640563200, 1640649600, 1640736000, 
1640822400, 1640908800, 1640995200, 1641081600, 1641168000, 1641254400, 
1641340800, 1641427200, 1641513600, 1641600000, 1641686400, 1641772800, 
1641859200, 1641945600, 1642032000, 1642118400, 1642204800, 1642291200, 
1642377600, 1642464000, 1642550400, 1642636800, 1642723200, 1642809600, 
1642896000, 1642982400, 1643068800, 1643155200, 1643241600, 1643328000, 
1643414400, 1643500800, 1643587200, 1643673600, 1643760000, 1643846400, 
1643932800, 1644019200, 1644105600, 1644192000, 1644278400, 1644364800, 
1644451200, 1644537600, 1644624000, 1644710400, 1644796800, 1644883200, 
1644969600, 1645056000, 1645142400, 1645228800, 1645315200, 1645401600, 
1645488000, 1645574400, 1645660800, 1645747200, 1645833600, 1645920000, 
1646006400, 1646092800, 1646179200, 1646265600, 1646352000, 1646438400, 
1646524800, 1646611200, 1646697600, 1646784000, 1646870400, 1646956800, 
1647043200, 1647129600, 1647216000, 1647302400, 1647388800, 1647475200, 
1647561600, 1647648000, 1647734400, 1647820800, 1647907200, 1647993600, 
1648080000, 1648166400, 1648252800, 1648339200, 1648425600, 1648512000, 
1648598400, 1648684800, 1648771200, 1648857600, 1648944000, 1649030400, 
1649116800, 1649203200, 1649289600, 1649376000, 1649462400, 1649548800, 
1649635200, 1649721600, 1649808000, 1649894400, 1649980800, 1650067200, 
1650153600, 1650240000, 1650326400, 1650412800, 1650499200, 1650585600, 
1650672000, 1650758400, 1650844800, 1650931200, 1651017600, 1651104000, 
1651190400, 1651276800, 1651363200, 1651449600, 1651536000, 1651622400, 
1651708800, 1651795200, 1651881600, 1651968000, 1652054400, 1652140800, 
1652227200, 1652313600, 1652400000, 1652486400, 1652572800, 1652659200, 
1652745600, 1652832000, 1652918400, 1653004800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Inflation = structure(c(2.62, 2.723, 
2.774, 2.825, 2.877, 2.928, 2.979, 3.031, 3.082, 3.133, 3.185, 
3.236, 3.287, 3.339, 3.39, 3.441, 3.493, 3.544, 3.595, 3.647, 
3.698, 3.749, 3.801, 3.852, 3.903, 3.955, 4.006, 4.057, 4.109, 
4.16, 4.16, 4.214, 4.24, 4.267, 4.294, 4.321, 4.347, 4.374, 4.401, 
4.428, 4.455, 4.481, 4.508, 4.535, 4.562, 4.588, 4.615, 4.642, 
4.669, 4.695, 4.722, 4.749, 4.776, 4.803, 4.829, 4.856, 4.883, 
4.91, 4.936, 4.963, 4.99, 4.99, 5.016, 5.029, 5.042, 5.055, 5.067, 
5.08, 5.093, 5.106, 5.119, 5.132, 5.145, 5.158, 5.171, 5.184, 
5.196, 5.209, 5.222, 5.235, 5.248, 5.261, 5.274, 5.287, 5.3, 
5.313, 5.325, 5.338, 5.351, 5.364, 5.377, 5.39, 5.389, 5.388, 
5.387, 5.387, 5.386, 5.385, 5.385, 5.384, 5.384, 5.383, 5.382, 
5.382, 5.381, 5.38, 5.38, 5.379, 5.378, 5.378, 5.377, 5.376, 
5.376, 5.375, 5.375, 5.374, 5.373, 5.373, 5.372, 5.371, 5.371, 
5.37, 5.37, 5.362, 5.358, 5.355, 5.351, 5.347, 5.343, 5.339, 
5.335, 5.331, 5.327, 5.324, 5.32, 5.316, 5.312, 5.308, 5.304, 
5.3, 5.296, 5.293, 5.289, 5.285, 5.281, 5.277, 5.273, 5.269, 
5.265, 5.262, 5.258, 5.254, 5.25, 5.22, 5.231, 5.237, 5.243, 
5.248, 5.254, 5.26, 5.265, 5.271, 5.277, 5.282, 5.288, 5.294, 
5.299, 5.305, 5.311, 5.316, 5.322, 5.328, 5.333, 5.339, 5.345, 
5.35, 5.356, 5.362, 5.367, 5.373, 5.379, 5.384, 5.39, 5.39, 5.444, 
5.47, 5.497, 5.524, 5.551, 5.577, 5.604, 5.631, 5.658, 5.685, 
5.711, 5.738, 5.765, 5.792, 5.818, 5.845, 5.872, 5.899, 5.925, 
5.952, 5.979, 6.006, 6.033, 6.059, 6.086, 6.113, 6.14, 6.166, 
6.193, 6.22, 6.22, 6.259, 6.279, 6.299, 6.318, 6.338, 6.358, 
6.377, 6.397, 6.417, 6.436, 6.456, 6.476, 6.495, 6.515, 6.535, 
6.554, 6.574, 6.594, 6.613, 6.633, 6.653, 6.672, 6.692, 6.712, 
6.731, 6.751, 6.771, 6.79, 6.81, 6.8, 6.815, 6.823, 6.831, 6.839, 
6.846, 6.854, 6.862, 6.87, 6.877, 6.885, 6.893, 6.901, 6.908, 
6.916, 6.924, 6.932, 6.939, 6.947, 6.955, 6.963, 6.97, 6.978, 
6.986, 6.994, 7.001, 7.009, 7.017, 7.025, 7.032, 7.04, 7.05, 
7.068, 7.083, 7.097, 7.111, 7.125, 7.139, 7.154, 7.168, 7.182, 
7.196, 7.21, 7.225, 7.239, 7.253, 7.267, 7.281, 7.295, 7.31, 
7.324, 7.338, 7.352, 7.366, 7.381, 7.395, 7.409, 7.423, 7.437, 
7.452, 7.466, 7.48, 7.48, 7.508, 7.522, 7.536, 7.55, 7.564, 7.577, 
7.591, 7.605, 7.619, 7.633, 7.647, 7.661, 7.675, 7.689, 7.703, 
7.717, 7.731, 7.745, 7.759, 7.772, 7.786, 7.8, 7.814, 7.828, 
7.842, 7.856, 7.87, 7.87, 7.913, 7.935, 7.956, 7.978, 8, 8.021, 
8.043, 8.065, 8.086, 8.108, 8.129, 8.151, 8.173, 8.194, 8.216, 
8.237, 8.259, 8.281, 8.302, 8.324, 8.345, 8.367, 8.389, 8.41, 
8.432, 8.454, 8.475, 8.497, 8.518, 8.54, 8.54, 7.976, 7.694, 
7.412, 7.13, 6.849, 6.567, 6.285, 6.003, 5.721, 5.439, 5.157, 
4.875, 4.593, 4.311, 4.029, 3.747, 3.466, 3.184, 2.902, 2.62, 
2.338, 2.056, 1.774, 1.492, 1.21, 0.928, 0.646, 0.365, 8.26, 
8.26, 8.281, 8.291, 8.301, 8.312, 8.322, 8.332, 8.343, 8.353, 
8.363, 8.374, 8.384, 8.394, 8.405, 8.415, 8.425, 8.435, 8.446, 
8.456, 8.466), tsp = c(2021.00821917808, 2022.14246575342, 365
), class = "ts"), ATOM_12 = c(0, 0.768450999999999, -0.144307999999999, 
1.469351, -0.275023000000001, 0.310776000000001, -2.190437, 0.935952999999998, 
0.880585, -0.343722, 2.290039, -1.299675, 1.819661, 3.235397, 
0.872935999999999, -2.396992, -0.929673999999999, -3.269912, 
-2.092005, 1.964466, -1.614958, -0.862821, 1.705257, -2.08337, 
0.256457999999999, 3.423559, 0.974142000000001, -0.0914530000000013, 
-0.831892, 0.602709000000001, 1.091922, -0.722394999999999, -0.129787, 
-1.925188, 3.720419, 0.770569000000002, 3.213972, 0.687902000000001, 
-0.655598000000001, -3.443265, 1.569681, -4.227759, 0.869804999999999, 
2.220243, -1.188532, -0.255972, -3.21471, 1.71472, -8.886411, 
3.061078, -3.436362, -1.324223, -0.499362, 2.704111, -0.531815999999999, 
1.353158, -0.844422, -1.701433, -0.649756999999999, 0.520512999999999, 
1.405285, -0.236704000000001, 1.095375, 1.784502, -1.552568, 
-0.210929, 0.225085999999999, -1.684433, 0.216416000000001, 0.308268, 
-1.130974, -0.871013, -0.318483000000001, 0.881482, 0.110932999999999, 
0.749215000000001, 0.0211449999999989, 0.218928, -1.170834, -0.487976, 
0.0718540000000001, -2.465136, -0.574975, 1.124191, 0.242291, 
-1.198673, 0.402508000000001, 0.506065999999999, 0.799098000000001, 
0.730930000000001, 0.423803999999999, -0.893127, 0.654536, 0.0530019999999993, 
0.445621000000001, 1.284927, -0.389104, -0.232984999999999, -0.997703000000001, 
1.236016, 1.236248, -0.338352, -1.016938, -0.932185, -0.364051, 
-0.318175, -0.252107000000001, -0.178977999999999, -0.0171030000000005, 
-1.02411, -0.473234, 0.931471999999999, 0.959963, 0.0827190000000009, 
-0.0077619999999996, -0.000346000000000402, -0.0436779999999999, 
0.30551, -0.155068, 0.20257, 0.38923, 0.456327, -0.244622999999999, 
0.124689999999999, -0.39812, 0.698427000000001, 0.237, 0.556457999999999, 
0.426603, -0.874836999999999, 0.549841000000001, 0.412205999999999, 
0.505001999999999, -0.560478999999999, 1.168624, 0.344392000000001, 
0.353116, -0.0516909999999999, 0.140777, 2.003192, 0.684851999999999, 
0.239771000000001, 3.172934, -0.237224999999999, -0.0263080000000002, 
-2.206606, 0.348984000000002, -2.003077, 2.489323, 0.876179, 
-0.134996999999998, 0.899183999999998, 0.771856, 2.4799, -1.207744, 
-0.00914799999999971, 0.299163999999998, 1.321087, -0.638766, 
-4.210718, -0.376631, 6.474625, 2.438278, -2.15608, 7.713537, 
0.629016999999997, -1.523784, 0.0270690000000045, 2.773891, -3.49248100000001, 
7.44105500000001, 3.688419, -10.750675, -3.349855, 9.54159, 1.531383, 
1.278389, -3.278534, 0.104503999999999, -2.278534, -3.67284, 
0.282314, 2.261578, 1.625148, 0.919708999999997, 0.0336989999999986, 
-2.073223, 0.0129009999999994, -1.519318, 1.516537, -1.744041, 
0.234271999999997, -2.70319, -0.445202000000002, 1.403038, 1.176601, 
-0.872917000000001, -0.765926, 0.129284000000006, -0.725151000000004, 
-0.528548000000001, 3.243456, 0.751412000000002, -1.551045, -0.288059000000004, 
1.7323, -1.47863, 0.976157999999998, 7.94501899999999, -6.45402199999999, 
1.303494, 1.351371, -2.146354, -0.00766399999999834, 0.0947379999999995, 
-0.291747999999998, 1.352718, -0.902290000000001, -0.614044, 
-0.602741999999999, -0.583190000000002, 0.980506000000005, -0.858833000000004, 
-3.726265, 0.965676000000002, -1.04041700000001, 0.511337000000005, 
-0.667852000000003, -0.448801, -3.02043, 0.959962999999998, -2.72793, 
1.497579, 1.277567, 1.621226, 1.028556, 0.061557999999998, -1.715387, 
-0.628062999999997, -2.8534, -0.147214000000002, 0.618652000000001, 
0.721138, -0.576170000000001, -0.840225, 1.665653, 4.300472, 
-4.549656, -3.500671, -0.207899000000001, -0.0406820000000003, 
0.866524000000002, -2.747341, 0.0804520000000011, 1.835981, 0.161943000000001, 
-2.813638, -0.547495000000001, 1.082788, -0.542214999999999, 
-0.536637000000002, 1.963313, -1.03714, -0.637018000000001, 2.088718, 
3.698553, 1.052443, -1.450688, 2.721859, 2.587021, -2.568958, 
-3.008051, 1.337461, 2.292092, 2.213127, 3.70072200000001, -0.567009000000006, 
3.69661300000001, 2.687057, -3.193767, 1.377167, -1.639939, -2.61787, 
-0.937126000000006, 2.87719300000001, 0.884902999999994, 1.45171800000001, 
-2.558762, 2.830845, -1.238228, 4.382153, -4.396325, -0.894850999999996, 
-1.19896, 1.94291, -4.64021, -5.267585, 5.24646, 1.509849, -0.106417999999998, 
-3.45520800000001, -2.252901, -0.634284999999998, -0.392779000000001, 
-1.905815, 0.978232999999999, 0.798630000000003, -2.560585, 3.105929, 
1.551475, -0.234009, 0.452113000000001, 0.423272999999998, -1.193898, 
0.421952000000001, -1.76335, -2.589596, 0.494384999999998, -0.697737, 
0.833891000000001, 1.758135, -0.404425999999997, -0.539122000000003, 
-1.034979, -0.270755999999999, -0.447303000000002, -2.401129, 
1.021316, 0.425722, -0.342366999999999, 2.280836, 2.581465, -3.055836, 
4.674464, -0.308033000000002, 1.105852, 1.8862, -3.561177, 0.439312000000001, 
-2.860038, 0.281640999999997, -0.564084999999999, 2.25436, -2.054669, 
-0.516483000000001, -0.309881000000001, -0.921832999999999, 0.542701999999998, 
0.0692550000000018, 2.091132, -0.821338999999998, 0.519311999999999, 
-0.053370000000001, -0.850424999999998, 0.190307000000001, 0.0597499999999975, 
0.165512, 0.983316000000002, -1.061737, 0.687360999999999, 1.07477, 
-0.437861999999999, 0.811810999999999, -0.164674999999999, -1.207012, 
0.491052999999997, 2.002691, 0.570558999999999, -1.068854, -1.565735, 
-2.428472, 0.824852, -0.849135999999998, 0.406713, -0.688822000000002, 
-2.805074, 0.860166000000003, 0.0575009999999985, -0.731065999999998, 
0.136664999999997, 0.0878300000000003, -0.899767000000001, 0.758488000000003, 
0.590805, -0.353554000000003, -0.986991999999997, -0.215914000000001, 
0.181602999999999, -0.941174, -0.196431999999998, -1.78718, 1.159562, 
-0.751888999999998, -1.274645, -1.598838, 0.145472999999999, 
-0.213269999999998, -0.219610000000003, 2.283331, -2.023577, 
-0.179175000000001, -1.198112, -0.778647000000001, -2.89238, 
0.799073, -2.876914, -1.017805, 0.604222, 0.511077999999999, 
1.527941, -1.334906, 0.460435, -1.336386, 0.718935, 0.345134)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2021-04-01", 
"2021-04-02", "2021-04-03", "2021-04-04", "2021-04-05", "2021-04-06", 
"2021-04-07", "2021-04-08", "2021-04-09", "2021-04-10", "2021-04-11", 
"2021-04-12", "2021-04-13", "2021-04-14", "2021-04-15", "2021-04-16", 
"2021-04-17", "2021-04-18", "2021-04-19", "2021-04-20", "2021-04-21", 
"2021-04-22", "2021-04-23", "2021-04-24", "2021-04-25", "2021-04-26", 
"2021-04-27", "2021-04-28", "2021-04-29", "2021-04-30", "2021-05-01", 
"2021-05-02", "2021-05-03", "2021-05-04", "2021-05-05", "2021-05-06", 
"2021-05-07", "2021-05-08", "2021-05-09", "2021-05-10", "2021-05-11", 
"2021-05-12", "2021-05-13", "2021-05-14", "2021-05-15", "2021-05-16", 
"2021-05-17", "2021-05-18", "2021-05-19", "2021-05-20", "2021-05-21", 
"2021-05-22", "2021-05-23", "2021-05-24", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-26", 
"2021-05-27", "2021-05-28", "2021-05-29", "2021-05-30", "2021-05-31", 
"2021-06-01", "2021-06-02", "2021-06-03", "2021-06-04", "2021-06-05", 
"2021-06-06", "2021-06-07", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-10", 
"2021-06-11", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-13", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", 
"2021-06-16", "2021-06-17", "2021-06-18", "2021-06-19", "2021-06-20", 
"2021-06-21", "2021-06-22", "2021-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2021-06-25", 
"2021-06-26", "2021-06-27", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-29", "2021-06-30", 
"2021-07-01", "2021-07-02", "2021-07-03", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05", 
"2021-07-06", "2021-07-07", "2021-07-08", "2021-07-09", "2021-07-10", 
"2021-07-11", "2021-07-12", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-14", "2021-07-15", 
"2021-07-16", "2021-07-17", "2021-07-18", "2021-07-19", "2021-07-20", 
"2021-07-21", "2021-07-22", "2021-07-23", "2021-07-24", "2021-07-25", 
"2021-07-26", "2021-07-27", "2021-07-28", "2021-07-29", "2021-07-30", 
"2021-07-31", "2021-08-01", "2021-08-02", "2021-08-03", "2021-08-04", 
"2021-08-05", "2021-08-06", "2021-08-07", "2021-08-08", "2021-08-09", 
"2021-08-10", "2021-08-11", "2021-08-12", "2021-08-13", "2021-08-14", 
"2021-08-15", "2021-08-16", "2021-08-17", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-19", 
"2021-08-20", "2021-08-21", "2021-08-22", "2021-08-23", "2021-08-24", 
"2021-08-25", "2021-08-26", "2021-08-27", "2021-08-28", "2021-08-29", 
"2021-08-30", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-01", "2021-09-02", "2021-09-03", 
"2021-09-04", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-08", 
"2021-09-09", "2021-09-10", "2021-09-11", "2021-09-12", "2021-09-13", 
"2021-09-14", "2021-09-15", "2021-09-16", "2021-09-17", "2021-09-18", 
"2021-09-19", "2021-09-20", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-22", "2021-09-23", 
"2021-09-24", "2021-09-25", "2021-09-26", "2021-09-27", "2021-09-28", 
"2021-09-29", "2021-09-30", "2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03", 
"2021-10-04", "2021-10-05", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-07", "2021-10-08", 
"2021-10-09", "2021-10-10", "2021-10-11", "2021-10-12", "2021-10-13", 
"2021-10-14", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-16", "2021-10-17", "2021-10-18", 
"2021-10-19", "2021-10-20", "2021-10-21", "2021-10-22", "2021-10-23", 
"2021-10-24", "2021-10-25", "2021-10-26", "2021-10-27", "2021-10-28", 
"2021-10-29", "2021-10-30", "2021-10-31", "2021-11-01", "2021-11-02", 
"2021-11-03", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-06", "2021-11-07", 
"2021-11-08", "2021-11-09", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-11", "2021-11-12", 
"2021-11-13", "2021-11-14", "2021-11-15", "2021-11-16", "2021-11-17", 
"2021-11-18", "2021-11-19", "2021-11-20", "2021-11-21", "2021-11-22", 
"2021-11-23", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-25", "2021-11-26", "2021-11-27", 
"2021-11-28", "2021-11-29", "2021-11-30", "2021-12-01", "2021-12-02", 
"2021-12-03", "2021-12-04", "2021-12-05", "2021-12-06", "2021-12-07", 
"2021-12-08", "2021-12-09", "2021-12-10", "2021-12-11", "2021-12-12", 
"2021-12-13", "2021-12-14", "2021-12-15", "2021-12-16", "2021-12-17", 
"2021-12-18", "2021-12-19", "2021-12-20", "2021-12-21", "2021-12-22", 
"2021-12-23", "2021-12-24", "2021-12-25", "2021-12-26", "2021-12-27", 
"2021-12-28", "2021-12-29", "2021-12-30", "2021-12-31", "2022-01-01", 
"2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", 
"2022-01-07", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-10", "2022-01-11", 
"2022-01-12", "2022-01-13", "2022-01-14", "2022-01-15", "2022-01-16", 
"2022-01-17", "2022-01-18", "2022-01-19", "2022-01-20", "2022-01-21", 
"2022-01-22", "2022-01-23", "2022-01-24", "2022-01-25", "2022-01-26", 
"2022-01-27", "2022-01-28", "2022-01-29", "2022-01-30", "2022-01-31", 
"2022-02-01", "2022-02-02", "2022-02-03", "2022-02-04", "2022-02-05", 
"2022-02-06", "2022-02-07", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-09", "2022-02-10", 
"2022-02-11", "2022-02-12", "2022-02-13", "2022-02-14", "2022-02-15", 
"2022-02-16", "2022-02-17", "2022-02-18", "2022-02-19", "2022-02-20", 
"2022-02-21", "2022-02-22", "2022-02-23", "2022-02-24", "2022-02-25", 
"2022-02-26", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-28", "2022-03-01", "2022-03-02", 
"2022-03-03", "2022-03-04", "2022-03-05", "2022-03-06", "2022-03-07", 
"2022-03-08", "2022-03-09", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-11", "2022-03-12", 
"2022-03-13", "2022-03-14", "2022-03-15", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-17", 
"2022-03-18", "2022-03-19", "2022-03-20", "2022-03-21", "2022-03-22", 
"2022-03-23", "2022-03-24", "2022-03-25", "2022-03-26", "2022-03-27", 
"2022-03-28", "2022-03-29", "2022-03-30", "2022-03-31", "2022-04-01", 
"2022-04-02", "2022-04-03", "2022-04-04", "2022-04-05", "2022-04-06", 
"2022-04-07", "2022-04-08", "2022-04-09", "2022-04-10", "2022-04-11", 
"2022-04-12", "2022-04-13", "2022-04-14", "2022-04-15", "2022-04-16", 
"2022-04-17", "2022-04-18", "2022-04-19", "2022-04-20", "2022-04-21", 
"2022-04-22", "2022-04-23", "2022-04-24", "2022-04-25", "2022-04-26", 
"2022-04-27", "2022-04-28", "2022-04-29", "2022-04-30", "2022-05-01", 
"2022-05-02", "2022-05-03", "2022-05-04", "2022-05-05", "2022-05-06", 
"2022-05-07", "2022-05-08", "2022-05-09", "2022-05-10", "2022-05-11", 
"2022-05-12", "2022-05-13", "2022-05-14", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-16", 
"2022-05-17", "2022-05-18", "2022-05-19", "2022-05-20"))
```

Code:

```
ardl_model1 <- dLagM::ardlDlm(ATOM_12 ~ Inflation, data = data_1, p = 1, q = 2)
summary(ardl_model1)
fcst_7_days <- dLagM::forecast(ardl_model1, x = data_1$Inflation, h = 7)
fcst_7_days
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply runing

> `plot.ts(fcst_7_days$forecasts)`

[image]